# How to `replaceWith` directive element with template in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my directive, I am using 2 template. according to the `index` the template are switched.

the problems is after find the `index` we are calling a method as `element.html()` to replace the updated template.

But that's makes the `directive` element wrapped with that. I don't want to wrapped my template. how to do this?

here is the result i am getting:

```
<program-name name="titre1" data-page="Home" index="0" ng-repeat="appName in appNames" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><h2 class="que t0" ng-click="callMe()">titre1arif</h2></program-name>
```

this is what i am looking for :

```
<h2 class="que t0" ng-click="callMe()">titre1arif</h2>
```

any one help me to get this?
[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87rqgqbp/)

here is my js :

```
// Code goes here
"use strict";
angular.module('tcpApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.appNames=[{title:'titre1'},
                   {title:'titre2'},
                   {title:'titre3'}];

})
.directive('programName', function ( $compile ) {
        return {
            restrict    : 'AE',
            replace     : true,
            scope       : {
                            name:'@',
                            index:'@'
                        },

            link        : function (scope, element, attr) {
                            scope.callMe = function () {
                                console.log($(element).prop('class'));
                            }

                            var getTemplate = function( index ) {
                              return Number(index) ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>';
                             }

                             element.html(getTemplate(scope.index));

                            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                        }
        }
    })
```

Comment: If you are hardcoding index in the element then you could just use `template` function and return. replace will work as is (though replace option has been deprecated). You could also do ` element.contents().unwrap();` after compiling.

Comment: I am not hardcoding the index here. i am counting from the data (ng-repeat)

Comment: `index="0"` it looks hardcoded to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `replaceWith` or `unwrap` after the element has been compiled.

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        //....

        element.html(getTemplate(scope.index));

        $compile(element.contents())(scope);

        element.replaceWith(element.contents());
        //Or do
        //element.contents().unwrap();
      }
```

```js
// Code goes here
"use strict";
angular.module('tcpApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.appNames = [{
      title: 'titre1'
    }, {
      title: 'titre2'
    }, {
      title: 'titre3'
    }];

  })
  .directive('programName', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        name: '@',
        index: '@'
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.callMe = function() {
          console.log($(element).prop('class'));
        }

        var getTemplate = function(index) {
          return Number(index) ? '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>';
        }

        element.html(getTemplate(scope.index));

        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        //element.replaceWith(element.contents());
        //element.contents().unwrap();
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tcpApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <program-name name="titre1" data-page="Home" index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="appName in appNames" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <h2 class="que t0" ng-click="callMe()">titre1arif</h2>
  </program-name>
</div>
```

Also note that you do not need to do `$(element)` as it is redundant, element is already jq(lite/uery) wrapped. And in your template you probably meant to use live `$index` from repeater, `index="{{$index}}"`. Also note that directive `replace` option will only work if your directive has a template specified with `template` or `templateUrl`. The `replace` option has been deprecated as well.

Had the `index` been assigned as a static string (ex: `index="0"`) you could just use function argument syntax of template/templateUrl.

```
   return {
        restrict    : 'AE',
        replace     : true,
        scope       : {
                        name:'@',
                        index:'@'
                    },
        template: function(elm, attr){
           return Number(attr.index) ? 
               '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' 
                : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>';
        }
```

```js
// Code goes here
"use strict";
angular.module('tcpApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.appNames = [{
      title: 'titre1'
    }, {
      title: 'titre2'
    }, {
      title: 'titre3'
    }];

  })
  .directive('programName', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        name: '@',
        index: '@'
      },
      template: function(elm, attr){
           return Number(attr.index) ? 
               '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}</h2>' 
                : '<h2 class="que t{{index}}" ng-click=callMe()>{{name}}arif</h2>';
        },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.callMe = function() {
          console.log(element.prop('class'));
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tcpApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div data-page="Home"  ng-repeat="appName in appNames" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <program-name index="0" ng-if="$first"  name="titre1"></program-name>
    <program-name index="1" ng-if="!$first" name="titre1"></program-name>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `template` can we make this?

Comment: Not if index is dynamic. if it is hardcoded you can. I dont understand why do you say `index="0"` ?

Comment: say hardcoded, how to do. because i require first with `one` template and rest with another template. totally 6 element. can you show me a demo?

Comment: i cannot access fiddle as my proxy wont allow. There is a demo in my answer. Click on that arrow that says Show code snippet.

Comment: why don't you add in to answer as snippet? - your answer is interesting that's why.

Comment: Yes. very thanks! I am much Happy with your efforts.